# Best way to filter a huge table by another huge table in DB2 / SQL?

Tags: sql, join, db2

I'm facing a problem with a big query I made.

In simple terms, [TABLE A] contains around 6 million IDs, and [TABLE B] have around 4 million IDs. I need to append to [TABLE B] the IDs from [TABLE A] that are not already on [TABLE B] (many are repeated on both tables because they have other columns with different values). [Table A] and [Table B] are both CTE.

I have tried everything, from a LEFT OUTER JOIN where A.ID is null, to a NOT IN and all the way to a WHERE NOT EXISTS, but they all take ages to run:

```
SELECT
ID
OTHER COLUMNS
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL

SELECT
ID
OTHER COLUMNS
FROM A
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM B)
```

Is there any other method that you could think of that may achieve this result in a faster or more efficient way?

Comment: Make sure you have an `index` on the `ID` column in both tables.  I would expect `not exists` to be your fastest option, but as with all performance related questions, you'll need to review your `execution plan` to know for sure.

Comment: What are the indexes on the tables? What does the plan look like? And why did you tag MySQL and DB2, which one is it?

Comment: The other method you seek uses `NOT EXISTS(...)` . Given  notNULLable id-columns, all three will produce the same execution plan. (except in mysql, IIRC ?-)

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks for your reply. What do you mean with an index on the id column?

Comment: @stickybit It's DB2, I also tagged SQL because at the end it's SQL language and I just thought maybe something that works in MySQL might also work in DB2 in some variance

Comment: @Roger Jimenez HSJOINs like large SORTHEAPs. Show the query access plan from the [db2exfmt](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002353.html) utility.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment "Thanks for your reply. What do you mean with an index on the id column?", you need to ensure that bot tables have an index on the ID. 
Asuming that in both cases the ID is unique and the Primary key, you should run:

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
ALTER TABLE B ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

And afterwards it should run fine I would recommend you the NOT EXISTS clause as below:

```
SELECT
ID
OTHER COLUMNS
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM B WHERE A.ID = B.ID)
```

If it is still slow, then, group in smaller sets like below:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT TOP 100000 
ID
OTHER COLUMNS
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM B WHERE A.ID = B.ID);
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
BEGIN
     COMMIT
     BREAK
END
COMMIT;
END;
```

This will make separate transactions for the number of rows you have chosen on line "SELECT TOP 100000 ".

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation... Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that [Table A] and [Table B] are actually CTE, not physical tables, my bad, so I guess this approach of indexing can't be used :(

Comment: You can use the approach but just need to identify where are the original tables / fields and create an index on them. If possible primary Key Ok but if are not the primary key just create indexes on them.

Answer (score 0):

To select records from a not in b.  Generally an exception join will go a bit faster than a not in clause because the sql processor will fully utilize indexes.

```
select blah from table a exception join table b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not looking to add records to a table, I'm looking to select those records from the CTE [Table A] that are not already present in the other CTE [Table B]

Comment: Tweaked it to just select recs.

Comment: You can do select a.* from (sql statement) as a exception join (sql statement) as b on a.id = b.id    Where SQL statement are your two common table expressions or whatever with the exception join technique.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using GROUP BY for your columns? In T-SQL GROUP BY makes queries for CTE tables run about 30 times faster and on par with temp tables. You could also explore using the EXCEPT function to find the rows you need to append

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... this sounds promising, should I group all columns in both tables, or only the ID columns?